# input at most one variable called amount_available and at least one "1"

Tags: javascript

What I try is to put the `quantidad_disponible` as maximum of the input
and it pleads for `addEventListener` it tells me `null`. Maybe it is not `document` that I should place, since that object is created and maybe that is not how I should implement it, but as a function and place the `onchange` property in my HTML embedding of the `shoppingCartItemQuantity_` input.

```
<td class="table__cantidad">
  <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_" type="number" value="1" />
</td>
```

What I want to do is put in the input's `max` property, so that the input only lets through the `available_amount` and the input doesn't keep increasing its value, so I try this in the desired input:

```
<input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" type="number" value="1" max="${cantidad_disponible}" />
```

**as you can see in my code the first executable, neither the minimum nor the maximum work for me**

```js
const cantidad_disponible = document.querySelector('#articulos>#productos_content>.tr >.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
console.log(cantidad_disponible) 
 
 function updatecantidad(valor){
  let v = parseInt(valor);
  if (v < 1) valor = 1;
  if (v > cantidad_disponible) valor = cantidad_disponible;
}
```

```html
<table id="articulos"class="table">
        <thead>
           
            <tr>
            
            <TH>id </TH>
            
                <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
              
               
                <TH>Añadir</TH>
             
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="productos_content">
        
           
           <tr class="tr">
           <td class="id_n"> 15</td>
                <td class="cantidad_disponible">10</td>

<input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" onchange="updatecantidad(this.value);" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_" type="number"
                    value="1" >
```

```js
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", function() {
  let v = parseInt(this.value);
  if (v < 1) this.value = 1;
  if (v > 50) this.value = 50;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="50" id="inp">
```

Comment: Please translate your second paragraph to English.

Comment: Have you tried adding `min` and `max` to your element like this: <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" onchange="updatecantidad(this.value);" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_" type="number" min="1" max="50" value="1" >

Comment: @Barmar, I translated it